# Blender Camera View Setting

Tags: interface

Hi I am new to blender and still trying to get used to its user interface. I have few questions about the views.

1. how to turn on/off the button on the right edge?
2. How to turn on/off cursor and lights in the camera view?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. I recommend you go through the blender tutorials first https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tV1ajY2059g

Comment: Thank you I was the youtube channel list is very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Overlays and Gizmos visibility toggles]

You can toggle the visibility of 3D Viewport UI elements (aka Gizmos, ones on the right) via button 1, and Overlays in the scene via button 2. Also check out the dropdown arrow right after the buttons, there you can selectively toggle the visibility of some of those elements, like 3D Cursor, grid, lights' extras and more.